# Should we opt in for the special Hat Dash promo?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, winterbash

Just recieved the following email from Stack Exchange, and wanted to know if you guys think we should participate:

> Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".
>
> For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.  Examples:

[image: 2011 Hat Dash hats]

> This year, we're expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate, and redesigning the hat selection to be more appropriate to the entire network (no severed Wampa heads). Some of it is holiday-themed, some of it is a bit silly, and all of it is (hopefully) fun!

Note: Users who don't want to see the hats will be able to opt-out by clicking an "I hate hats" link.

Comment: I think it could be fun.

Comment: I think sci-fi needs something other than hats, which are gamer related.

Comment: @Pureferret Outside of Team Fortress 2, how are hats gamer related?

Comment: @Keen I think hats have spread to the rest of gaming as a general gaming trope...

Comment: What was the feedback from this event on [gaming.se]?

Comment: Generic is boring.  I counter-propose themed hats.  Jayne's should be available on SciFi.

Comment: Yes, yes, we must have Jayne's hat.

Comment: @Izkata: Who do I have to murder to get Jayne's hat?

Comment: @bitmask the Big Hair

Comment: @Keen Hat Dash was heavily influenced by Team Fortress 2.  Arqade (then Gaming)'s [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) chat room had a heavy TF2 following, spearheaded by myself (I was also the team-fortress-2 tag's top user before I had my account there deleted).  This was taken into account by the event designer whose name I can't recall.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FYI everyone: We've opted-in.  Expect to see hats this holiday season.

Comment: We requested special hats as well, I'm hoping by opting in early that we'll have more of a chance to get them. But it's up to Jin now. I pointed them to my answer on this topic to look for suggestions for custom hats.

Answer (score 8):

The lack of severed Wampa heads seems to be unfair, particularly to Scifi.se :(

Otherwise, I say this looks like great fun, and I think we should participate!

After all, anyone who feels that such hat-related fun is ill suited towards our serious nature here on Scifi.SE can always use the "I hate hats!" button to opt out.

Comment: Actually, haberdashery is for ribbons. Millinery is hats. /pedantic :P

Comment: @Aarthi Darnit!  No wonder that guy in the hat shop looked at me so oddly!

Comment: [It seems my use of the term was merely archaic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/2011/11/17/), and perhaps not outright incorrect: *"At various times throughout its history, the term "haberdasher" has referred to a dealer of hats or caps"*

Comment: GASP! TOUCHE SIR.

Comment: I too have heard haberdasher referring to hat makers.

Answer (score 4):

Vote for which hats we want to have in: [Hat suggestions 2012](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2420/2565)

---

I vaguely remember this from last year. Essentially, there were two types of hats, some that were generic, and others that were specific to a tag. We could make suggestions for the specific ones. I would like to propose the following:

- [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) Wookie Hat
- [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) Tribble
- [firefly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefly)- Jayne's hat
- [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)- Generic Wizard hat
- [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings)- Maybe a battle helmet?
- [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama)- Brain Slug Hat
- [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) - Magneto's helmet
- [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) - Doctor Fate helmet

I'm going to cap this list at what we have now, because there is very little chance of us getting anything more than this. Even getting this many would be a bit of a surprise. But I would appreciate adding photos of these to this answer.

Comment: Star Trek: [Tribble](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tribble) hat!

Comment: @bitmask Please please a tribble hat! I've always wanted a tribble ;)

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout: Alternatives include Klingon forehead ridges and a Romulan wig. But the Tribble would win for whimsy!

Comment: @bitmask Forehead ridges! Oh, you are good at this. Keep 'em coming :) This may just make me want to dress up at a comicon...

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout: Sorry, Klingon ridges are a bit hard to top (no pun intended). But I still got one for Doctor Who: A Fez ;)

Comment: Futurama: Brain Slug hat!

Comment: DC: Doctor Fate helmet

Comment: Marvel: Magneto Helmet, or Cyclops visor

Answer (score 4):

Brain Slug Hat

[image]

Doc Brown Mind Reader Hat

[image]

Comment: "Brain Slug Hat" [Like this](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Triboniophorus_Tyrannus)?