# Hat suggestions 2012

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, winterbash

Since we [opted in](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2415/2565) to the hat promotion thing, I thought it would be a good idea to vote which site-specific hats would be most wanted by the community. It seems to be unclear if and how many hats we can get, but if we post one answer per suggestion right here, we can use votes to determine which ones the community wants most.

Comment: Listen, guys, while I really love -- ***LOVE*** -- these hat suggestions, I'm not sure we'll have the design resources to make site-specific hats *this year*. I know, it's really disappointing and I hate to shut this down. I **promise**: if we decide to do special hats, I will reopen this in a heartbeat.

Comment: @Aarthi: That's a bummer. I specifically asked previous to posting this question and was under the impression that it would be possible to have site-specific hats. However, I vaguely remember some of us discussing to do the work ourselves, if you guys don't have the resources for that (which I totally understand). All that would be needed would be a place for the community to contribute the hat designs, and some guidelines as to how the art has to be formatted, etc. Do you think such a community-driven effort could be supported by SE?

Comment: @Aarthi maybe one special hat for sites that care enough to ask?

Answer (score 13):

### [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) The Sorting Hat

[image: The Sorting Hat - *Harry Potter*]

Answer (score 12):

### [firefly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefly) Jayne's hat

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Doc Brown "thinking cap".

[image: "thinking cap"]

Comment: Great... I support this one.

Answer (score 11):

### [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who) The Doctor's cool [fez](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fez).

[image: The Eleventh Doctor with a fez]

Comment: +1 A fez + bowtie combo would be even better

Answer (score 10):

### [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) Brain slug hat

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**[lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) King Aragorn Crown**
[image]

Comment: Is the crown really **THAT** recognizable as LOTR?

Comment: @DVK Depends how big of a LotR movie fan you are I guess. Would the Witch King crown be better? I thought of Gandalf's hat, but thought that might get confused with Dumbledore.

Comment: @Xantec - I think Aragorn's crown is a good choice. I'm not everybody, but it's recognizable to me. The Witch King's hat is like an entire helmet, isn't it? Or do you mean the crown when Frodo sees him while wearing the Ring, before he's stabbed?

Comment: Sauron's Helmet/crown is more recognizable

Comment: @Slytherincess I meant the crown as seen when the ring was on. Although if full face masks are doable, as [mentioned by Grace Note](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2420/hat-suggestions-2012/2433#comment8045_2433), then the helmet would work too I guess.

Comment: The wingéd crown of the sea kings.

Answer (score 9):

### [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) Batman's Mask

[image: A Batman Mask]

Answer (score 8):

**[star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) R2-D2 Dome Hat**
[image: R2-D2 dome]

Answer (score 8):

### [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) or [half-life](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life) Hat-Crab*

[image]

<sup>*</sup> Headcrab hat

Answer (score 7):

### [alien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien) *Signs* foil hat.

[image: pic]

Comment: I want one. I have the technology...

Answer (score 7):

### [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) Darth Vader's helmet

[image: Darth Vader's helmet]

Comment: Since it is a full face helmet how would it work with the avatar? Just sit on top of it? or would the front be open, a la the cave on Dagobah?

Comment: @Xantec When we did this on Arqade, the front was partially open (I think it was just the eye area, though). Let me see if I can find an image from back then of someone wearing the helmet.

Comment: @Xantec [Here is an image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OqOcE.png) cutout of what is visible from [Raven Dreamer's avatar](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0c02079e74de8563fdfa7e4ac1d87d76?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) with the helmet on.

Answer (score 6):

### [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) The hound's helmet

[image: The hound's helmet]

Answer (score 5):

### [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) Tribble hat

[image: tribble hat]

Comment: At the rate they breed a Tribble hat should be just about given away.

Comment: I always thought that Tribbles would make good slippers.

Answer (score 5):

### [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) One or more of Guinan's hats

[image: Three of Guinan's hats]

Comment: Three seems good for an example..  Google for Guinan and there's more!

Comment: She did have a good collection of hats.

Answer (score 3):

## [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) Some Borg implants

[image: Locutus]

Answer (score 3):

### [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) / [magical-creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-creatures) Cat Hat

[image: Pic]

Comment: Been there, got that hat.

Answer (score 2):

### [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who) TARDIS hat

[image: TARDIS hat - *Doctor Who*]

Answer (score 2):

### [robots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) [space-exploration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-exploration) Lost in Space B-9 robot dome [image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

**[star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) Masaka Mask Hat**
[image: Masaka Mask]

Answer (score 0):

### [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) Wookie Hat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)Diadem of Ravenclaw

[image]

Answer (score -6):

### [timelord](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timelord) Timelord Santa Hat

[image: What say you, Pius?]

Well, with the holidays coming up, I was thinking from a practical standpoint, especially as my favorite SFF.se question is "Is Santa a Timelord?" (@TangoOversway!) Perhaps instead of a pom-pom on the end of the hat, we could customize it to have a plushie Death Star on it or something.

Comment: The issue is that the "Santa hat" would be the only thing left and it wouldn't have anything to do with your node-less buddy there. And there's going to be a regular Santa hat, anyway.

Comment: Darn! Well, perhaps my suggestion of the Sorting Hat makes up for this lemon :)

Comment: @bitmask -- Oh, and I didn't mean for the Santa hat to suggest a connection to *Harry Potter*. I just had that image on hand. I can see why that might have been confusing, people trying to connect the two. :)