# What happened to the hats?

Tags: discussion, support, site-promotion, winterbash

[We were going to have hats on the site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2418/3383)

What happened to them?

The holiday season is almost over!

Comment: You landed on the wrong temporal coordinates with your TARDIS; the holiday season is about to begin, not over (but you point remains valid).

Comment: @bitmask hehe the TARDIS never lies! Hanukkah is already over and the special is in 7 days. I would consider it as "almost over".

Comment: Does the downvote mean that people **don't** want the hats? That is very confusing x_x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hats will arrive at 00:00Z UTC on 19 December 2012! :D

Comment: [Ill make a link list here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2518/what-happened-to-the-hats/2523#comment8224_2521), what is the reason for the timing?

Comment: It just felt like the right couple of weeks to do this. :)

Comment: Eh.... Yes... but why not start it in the beginning of December so that **all** of the holidays are covered?

Comment: @TheDoctor We were also a bit constrained by time and available people. We had no way to get everything ready in time for the beginning of December. I'm sorry that some holidays got missed as a result. I hope you can still enjoy the hats!

Comment: @AnnaLear ok. At least I have an explanation ^_^  I would be glad to help out next time if this happens again.

Comment: @TheDoctor Well, we *are* [hiring](http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) right now... :)

Comment: @AnnaLear hmmmmmm

Answer (score 1):

Quotes from [se podcast #38](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/se-podcast-38-this-ones-at-least-a-410/) :

> People wear hats, especially winter-themed hats. Shouldn’t we celebrate all those hats? Definitely! Last year, we ran a project called Hatdash on our site about video games.. It was a huge hit, so we’re revamping the program this year for all sites that opt in. **It will go live on December 19th**. Hats!

Comment: [Hmmmmm](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2518/what-happened-to-the-hats/2521#comment8223_2520), very weird timing....

Answer (score 1):

The hats arrived on time and are alive and well. You can find the SF&F Winter Bash Leaderboard [here](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard).

Answer (score 0):

Aarthi later edited the comment, but at one point on 12/14, [she said](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=7273337#7273337)

> Also, hats arrive in 5 days. Five UTC days.

Dunno if that's *business* days or regular days, as no one understands how UTC works.

Comment: That is weird considering that part of the holiday season (for some people) is already over!

Comment: You don't need to understand UTC days. With a few exceptions that did not arise during the time period in question, a UTC day is exactly the same length as a day anywhere in the world. Besides, you'll find that most of West Africa has no problem with UTC and can convert it to local time without a hitch.

Comment: @Gilles That was a (admittedly bad) joke.

Answer (score -2):

On server fault, we're doing our own hats for the second year running.

https://serverfault.com/users?tab=reputation

As pointed out in a comment, many of us decided to add a hat to our gravatars ourselves:

https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2394/its-santa-time

Comment: That just involved **actually** changing your avatar!