# Where are the hats? (2013 edition)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, winterbash

[Last year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2415/1027) around this time Stack Exchange had a promotion called Winter Bash.  Will it be returning this year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Due to the unanimous acceptance to participate in the promotion last year, we moderators opted-in to the promotion this year.  The promotion will work the same as last year.  This year, the promotion will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014.

Comment: Yay, tomorrow is hat-day :) (+1)