# Are we doing hats again? (2014 edition)

Tags: discussion, winterbash

The Stack Exchange winter bash is looming, and I’ve seen hat-related posts on quite a few other Stacks, but not one here yet. We had [hats in 2013](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3228/3567) and [in 2012](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2415/3567).

**Are we doing hats again this year?**

Comment: Isn't it getting a bit... _old hat_?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We are doing hats. Based on the fact for the last 2 years there's been pretty much no complaint, we (the moderators) decided to just go ahead and submit the site for hats.

Comment: Hooray Hats :-D

Comment: I thought this would be the case, but I wanted to be sure. :)

Comment: I take my hat off to you (and then put it straight back on again, obviously).

Comment: When will this start?

Answer (score 7):

**I want hats.** Buffy's head is feeling distinctly bare.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Wait... you mean that's *not* you? Are others using fake avatars?!

Comment: @Wikis: Nope, no-one.

Comment: I am definitely a concentric series of orange and white squares, triangles and abstract shapes. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: @Zibbobz - we all started life in a similar way...

Comment: I, for one, have been a tiki-mask-head thingy from the day I was born. Errr... created.